# Collapsible div is shifting other items when it collapses and it works for one item on the loop

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I am pulling data from the database and looping through every item using a foreach loop, the data is returned but the collapsing view works for the first item only and the third item moves when the first item is collapsed. This is the code I have on the HTML view:

```
<div class="content-side col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @{
        foreach (var news in Model) {
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="single-item  wow fadeInUp animated animated animated animated">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <div class="img-holder">
                            <figure><a href="#"><img src="@news.file.Url" alt=""></a></figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-content">
                        <h4><a href="#">@news.Header</a></h4>
                           <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                   @news.Description
                               </div>
                        <div class="show-more">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

And these are the images showing what my problem is:
[image: it is displaying exactly as I want it here]

[image: the third image moves when I click the View More]

Please help.

Comment: can you post your css code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS,

```
.content-side{
font-size:0px;
}
.content-side .col-md-6{
float:none!important;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
font-size:14px;
}
.content-side>*{
font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Veera this works, why does it only collapse the first item on the list?

Comment: Actually it's " float and height" problem, you can use min-height instead of this solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap cols to adjust items in a grid, and content in each of the post is flexible vertically which in result items have inconsistent height, so the problem is that the bootstrap cols use float to put items in front of each other and float disturbs the layout from second row when elements have inconsistent height.
Solution to this is a little hack to the cols that i prefer and use, but you can try others solutions too, for your case use this

```
`.content-side div[class^="col-"]{
float:none !important;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin-right: -4px;
}`
```

Hope it will fix the issue

Comment: yes this works thank you so much, do you have any idea how I can make the "View more" tag collapse for the item that is selected?currently it works for only 1 item in the loop